# using "if and" statement to change specific cells red

Tags: vba, excel

I need help coming up with a code that changes specific cells red if one cell's date is smaller than todays date and if another cell is blank.

For example, if cell "I5" is smaller than todays date and if cell "G5" is blank than change the fill in cell "I5" to red. If else, than change the fill to green. And this needs to be repeated for each cell in column I.

This is the code I have so:

```
With Sheet1
    For Each rCell In .Range("I5", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp)).Cells
        If rCell.Value <= Date And Cells(46, 7).Value = "" Then
            rCell.Interior.Color = vbRed
            Else
            rCell.Interior.Color = vbGreen
        End If
    Next rCell
End With
```

But I cannot get much further than that.

If anyone has any ideas let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Cells(46, 7) is fixed, should it be fixed or should it look in column G on every row?

Comment: Instead of "date" you should use now(). Date is a Type

Comment: and where is your Problem exactly ? what does not work ?

Comment: @Fredrik `Date` is a valid function call in `VBA` which returns the current system date (whereas `Now` returns the system date and time).  As for the calculation, I'd say take a look at the `DateDiff` function

Comment: @Dave Guess I just got comfertable with now() :-)

Comment: Nothing wrong with `Now()`, it's very useful... but sometimes you just need the date :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cells(46, 7) is fixed, I below assume column G on every row.
Not sure about your "With Sheet1". Unless you created a variable that is named Sheet1 you should use Sheets("Sheet1"). Below how I would do it.

```
With Sheets("Sheet1") ' or with ActiveSheet
    For i = 5 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row
        If .Cells(i, 9).Value <= Date And .Cells(i, 7).Value = "" Then
            .Cells(i, 9).Interior.Color = vbRed
        Else
            .Cells(i, 9).Interior.Color = vbGreen
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: Beauty! Works great. Thanks.

Comment: OP is probably using Sheet1 as the .CodeName of the sheet, not a variable named "Sheet1".